# adding new documents not being show in ElasticSearch index

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am new to `ElasticsSearch` and was messing around with it today. I have a node running on my `localhost` and was creating/updating my `cat` index. As I was adding more `documents` into my `cat` indexes, I noticed that when I do a GET request to see all of the `documents` in `Postman`, the new `cats` I make are not being added. I started noticing the issue after I added my tenth `cat`. All code is below.

`ElasticSearch Version: 6.4.0
 Python Version: 3.7.4`

```
  my_cat_mapping = {
      "mappings": {
        "_doc": { 
          "properties": { 
            "breed":    { "type": "text"  }, 
            "info" : {
                "cat" :  {"type" : "text"},
                "name" :      {"type" : "text"},
                "age" : {"type" : "integer"},
                "amount"  : {"type" : "integer"}
            },  
            "created"  :  {
              "type":   "date", 
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }



cat_body = {
    "breed" : "Persian Cat",
        "info":{
            "cat":"Black Cat",
            "name": " willy",
            "age": 5,
            "amount": 1
        }

}



def document_add(index_name, doc_type, body, doc_id = None):
    """Funtion to add a document by providing index_name,
    document type, document contents as doc and document id."""
    resp = es.index(index=index_name, doc_type=doc_type, body=body, id=doc_id)
        print(resp)


document_add("cat", "cat_v1", cat_body, 100 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the document id is passed as 100 it just updates the same cat document. I'm assuming its not changed on every run !?

You have to change the document id `doc_id` with every time to add new cat instead of updating existing ones.

```
...

cat_id = 100
cat_body = {
    "breed" : "Persian Cat",
        "info":{
            "cat":"Black Cat",
            "name": " willy",
            "age": 5,
            "amount": 1
        }
}

...

document_add("cat", "cat_v1", cat_body, cat_id )
```

With this you can change both cat_id and cat_body to get new cats.